# Perl: print compilation warnings for do()

Tags: perl

I am using `do()` to execute a perl script. I wanted to make sure it was doing the right error checking, but I noticed that warnings don't get printed when I use `do()`. I left the following warning on purpose in my script. I see it when I run it on the command line

```
Useless use of numeric eq (==) in void context at utils/queryEvent/query_event.pl line 47.
```

When I use `do()`, this message is suppressed. I saw in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$@) that `$@` doesn't contain warnings, so I tried to add this before my call to `do()`, but I still don't see anything.

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    print "Warning @_\n";
};
do(...);
```

Is there a way I can still print the compilation/parsing warnings?

I'm using Perl v.5.22.1 on Windows 10.

**Added edit:**
Both the script calling `do()` and the script being run through `do()` have `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. It is only the parsing warning that isn't showing up. If I call warn in the do script, then I see that (I'm assuming stderr).

**Edit:**
Adding example script.
A minimal reproducible version is the following

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub test
{
    return 1;
}

main:
{
    (test() == 1);
}
```

Calling script

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

main:
{
    do('test.pl');
}
```

Comment: Does the script you're `do`ing turn on warnings? (A small [mcve] would be nice)

Comment: Yes, both the running script and script called with do have `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken. `do` doesn't affect warnings in the least.

There is no warning because there is nothing that should cause a warning. `(test() == 1)` isn't being evaluated in void context. Instead, its result is returned by `do`.

But while warnings AREN'T being silenced, exceptions ARE being silenced. Fixing this will fix the other.

Add a trailing `1` to the file loaded by `do`, and change the `do` as follows:

```perl
do('test.pl')
   or die( "Can't execute `./test.pl`: ".( $@ // $! ) );
```

The trailing `1` is used to signal the "caller" whether an error occurred or not. This has the side effect of cause `(test() == 1)` to be evaluated in void context as expected.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I didn't realize the context changed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `-w` or `-W` command-line switches will enable warnings throughout your program, including code included through a `do` statement.